# Login to AWS Console using account, user name, password

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using Chrome as a web browser

I logged in to the AWS Console using the following url:

```
https://signin.aws.amazon.com
```

I got a login form with three fields
    Account
    User
    Password

Under it, there was a link to login using a two-field form (email and password), I clicked on that link and logged in.

Anytime I want to login now, I get the two-field form. There are no links on that page to take me to the 3-field form.

This should be something simple. How do I go back to the 3-field form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the following link, just replace "account" in the URL with an appropriate account name.
https://account.signin.aws.amazon.com/console